# Можно ли использовать Bootstrap Popover в Vue без jQuery?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap, popover

Перевожу проект с Bootstrap-Vue на обычный Bootstrap

В проекте установлен Bootstrap 4.

В секции script мпортировал в кономпонент popover из Bootstrap

```
import "bootstrap/js/dist/popover"
```

Пробую инициализировать поповер на кнопка с помощью js

```
document.querySelector('#element').popover()
```

вместо

```
$('#element').popover()
```

В консоли появляется ошибка btn.popover is not a function

Можно ли использовать логику Popver.js без неорбходимости импортировать jQuery в проект?

Comment: необходимо заменить версию с Bootstrap 4 на Bootstrap 5, т.к 4 версия не будет работать без ```jquery```

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, а то не мог ничего найти.